# Use methods of instance of class stored in dictionary at runtime c#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, reflection, dictionary

Hello i have a problem in my code where i have to create an instance of class at run time. the classes inherits from  a generic interface and this type of classes are stored in dictionary. then at runtime, use the methods of this new instanced class.

Heres my code:

Classes

```
  public interface ILetters<T> where T : Item
    {
        Item SearchItem(T item);
    }
```

Item is an Absract Class, ItemA, ItemB, ItemC inherits from it.

Child Classes Inherits from ILetters, lets just say they implemented SearchItem() differntly

```
public class ClassA : ILetters<ItemTypeA>
public class ClassB : ILetters<ItemTypeB>
public class ClassC : ILetters<ItemTypeC>
```

Main:

```
Dictionary<string, Type> dictTypeSelected = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
            {
                {"A", typeof(ClassA)},
                {"B", typeof(ClassB},
                {"C", typeof(ClassC)},
            };

// Gets a string from user input
string type = combobox.SelectedItem.ToString();
var selectedType = Activator.CreateInstance(dictTypeSelected[type]);

selectedType.SearchItem() // <---- doesn't work.
```

is there a different approach or way i can fix this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are several solutions, I think, the main problem is generic interface.
At first look, there's no need for it here.

I'd suggest you to rebuild types hierarchy:

```
abstract class Item { }

interface ILetters
{
    Item SearchItem(Item item);
}

abstract class Letters<T> : ILetters
    where T : Item
{
    public Item SearchItem(Item item)
    {
        return SearchItemOverride((T)item);
    }

    protected abstract Item SearchItemOverride(T item);
}

class ItemA : Item { }
class ClassA : Letters<ItemA> 
{
    protected override Item SearchItemOverride(ItemA item)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you can easily do this:

```
var selectedType = (ILetters)Activator.CreateInstance(dictTypeSelected[type]);

selectedType.SearchItem(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my design. I think i implemented DI very ugly since I just started to learn about it. Your answer has solved my problem thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the major problem here is the var. Using var will cast your instance to an object.
You can try different alternatives here.

1. You can box the instance into a dynamic object and simply call the method with the risk to have a runtime exception
2. You can cast the instance to the concrete type but in this case I think you are not aware of it
3. You can call the method using reflection

In concrete:

```
1) dynamic selectedType = Activator.CreateInstance(...)
selectedType.SearchItem(...)
2) ClassA selectedType = Activator.CreateInstance(...)
selectedType.SearchItem(...)
3) object selectedType = Activator.CreateInstance(...)
MethodInfo searchMethod = selectedType.GetMethod("SearchItem")
searchMethod.Invoke(...)
```

Comment: "2)" definitely isn't an option. Usually, such task occurs, when concrete type is unknown.

Comment: 1.) making the type dynamic doesn't show the methods as for number
thanks for providing answers.

Comment: Of course dynamic doesn't work with intellisense but will solve your issue